# How to render an object from an array in MongoDB and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, react-redux

I'm not sure how to render an object from an array into react.

My MongoDB schema is

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userID: { type: String },
    dateTime: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    comments: [{
        userID: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
        likes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    }],
})
```

In react, I want to render just dateTime and likes.

```
function Post(post) {
    const {dateTime, likes } = post;
    return (
        <tr>
            <td>
                {dateTime}
            </td>
            <td>
                {likes}
            </td>
         
        </tr>
    );
  }
```

dateTime works fine and renders the data but Likes does not render anything. I have tried {comments.likes} but an error shows: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {dateTime, likes}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

```
function Post(post) {
    const {dateTime, comments.likes } = post;
    return (
        <tr>
            <td>
                {dateTime}
            </td>
            <td>
                {comments.likes}
            </td>

        </tr>
    );
  }
```

Does anyone know how to render "likes" so I can display them in react? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`comments` is an Array of object . So we need to iterate over to render the likes. Assuming you need to show the likes of the Post by summing up all the likes within the comments .

```
const {dateTime, comments} = post;

const getLikes = () => {
  const likes = comments.reduce((totalLikes, comment) =>  totalLikes + comment.likes , 0);
  return likes;
}

return (
  <tr>
      <td>
          {dateTime}
      </td>
      <td>
          {getLikes()}
      </td>
  </tr>
);
```